# Why does this code work? Rails 4, Record iteration with nested attributes in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Someone else helped me with this code

[Rails 4, retrieved many records with Model.where(related_model_id: 1), how to show each one in an individual view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305269/rails-4-retrieved-many-records-with-model-whererelated-model-id-1-how-to-sh/27305580#27305580)

It works great but I'm trying to figure out exactly why this code functions the way it does.

```
def show    
  @min_id = params[:min_id]
  @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
  @questions = @quiz.questions.order("id ASC")
 if @min_id
   @question = @questions.where("id > ?", @min_id).first
 else
   @question = @questions.first
 end
end
```

In the show view:

```
<%= @question.content %>

<%= link_to "Next question", quiz_path(@quiz, :min_id => @question.id) %>
```

From my understanding, it fetches `@quiz.questions` based upon the quiz id and assigns them in ascending order (which is 1, 2 ,3) to `@questions`.  Next it enters the if else block and assigns @question to the first question which is rendered in the view.

Next when the link is clicked in the view it submits the `@quiz.id` and the `@question.id = params[min_id: "1"]`,  because the current id of the question being shown is 1.  This is verified by hovering over the link which shows `http://localhost:3000/quizzes/1?min_id=1`

The `params[:mind_id = 1 ]` is then assigned to @min_id and used inside the if block to fetch the first record from @questions with the id = 1.

Here is where I'm confused.  On the second render, after the link is clicked, it's showing `http://localhost:3000/quizzes/1?min_id=1` in the address bar, why is the @question.content being rendered for `@questions.id = 2`?  Shouldn't it be 1?  The logic seems circular to me, and it seems like this code shouldn't even work properly.

What am I missing?  Why does it correctly go id = 1, then id = 2 when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, `min_id` is being used like pagination to fetch the next question for the quiz in question. (Unfortunate choice of words there.)

So this is your question (erm) about `"id > ?"` from the other answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305269/rails-4-retrieved-many-records-with-model-whererelated-model-id-1-how-to-sh/27305580#comment43074751_27305580) (ugh), coming back to haunt you. ;)

Steps:

- Get the questions for this quiz, and show me the first (and the first time through, it really is the first sequential question)
- Display a "Next question" link to the same quiz, passing the current question id in the query string as `min_id`
- After the link is clicked, `min_id` is now present and is used to get the **next** question, by retrieving all questions belonging to this quiz whose id is **greater than** the previous one (the `min_id` value), and selecting the `first` one from the record set. (This works because the questions were previously ordered ascending by id.)

Does that sound right?

(And based on your comment I think you're familiar with SQL query parameter escaping: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions)

Comment: The word "question" has stopped making sense to me.

Comment: Aha, ok that makes complete sense.  So the `id > ?` is where I was confused after all.  It's grabbing all the questions where the ID is greater than the one passing in from the link and assigning the first one.  Ok got it!  Thank you!